# Excel formule to an PowerPivot Formula

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I need to convert this Excel sheet formula to an PowerPivot formula:

```
=IF(D3=0,"NA",B3/D3)
```

B3 = F5
D3 = F13

Need to add the IF to this formula:

```
=SUM('data'[F5]) / SUM('data'[F13])
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Add the IF normal excel formula =IF(D3=0,"NA" in the powerpivot formula =SUM('data'[F5]) / SUM('data'[F13])

Comment: That is still not a question. A question ends with a question mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you ask for:

```
= IF (SUM('data'[F13]) = 0, 0, SUM('data'[F5]) / SUM('data'[F13]))
```